# unable to send mail in python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, email

I am trying to send a bunch of photos to my email address using the `email` module. But when I run my program nothing is happening. I am not able to figure out what's wrong in my program. How can I solve this problem?

Python code:

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

fromadd = 'fromadd@gmail.com'
toadd = 'toadd@gmail.com'

def send():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = fromadd
    msg['To'] = toadd
    msg['Subject'] = 'Photos'

    text = MIMEText('Pics')
    msg.attach(text)

    screenshot_data = open(files, 'rb').read()
    webcam_data = open(files, 'rb').read()

    send_image = MIMEImage(screenshot_data, name=os.path.basename(files))
    send_images = MIMEImage(webcam_data, name=os.path.basename(files))

    msg.attach(send_image)
    msg.attach(send_images)

    sessions = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', '587')
    sessions.ehlo()
    sessions.starttls()
    sessions.ehlo()
    sessions.login(fromadd, 'Password')
    sessions.sendmail(fromadd, toadd, msg.as_string())
    sessions.quit()


def main():

    global files

    for files in os.listdir(r'C:\NONE'):

        if os.path.isfile(files) and files.endswith(".jpg"):
            send()
            print('File Sent: ' + files) 
            os.remove(files)

    else:
        pass

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: As a side note: Why have you made `files` a global instead of just passing it as an argument to `send`? Also, why is a variable representing a single filename called `files` instead of, say, `file` or `filename`?

Comment: This is not the way you pass parameters to functions. Remove `global files` and pass the `files` variable (consider renaming this to a singular noun by the way) to your `send()` function.

Comment: Anyway, are you sure you actually have files that end in `.jpg` directly in the `C:\NONE` directory? Because if so, the `print` should be printing something out. If nothing is printing out, either you don't have any files there, or there's a problem with the logic in `main`; since `send` is never being called, the bug you're asking about can't be in `send`. (You may, of course, have bugs there as well, but if you can't even get that far, they don't matter yet.)

Comment: I thought **files** will only be accessible in main function so I declared global variable for files. I just called ** files** variable to make easy in my program

Comment: Yeah I have files which ends with .jpg in C:\NONE directory. I have called send in main function. Still I am not able to send mail. -- abarnert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns just the file names, not the full paths. So unless you run this program in `c:\NONE` or just happen to have a file with the same name in your current working directory, `os.path.isfile(files)` will return `False`, and so `send()` will never be called.

Even though it's not specific to Python - so many of the concrete tips in it do not apply - you might want to give Eric Lippert's [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read. Also remember Brian Kernighan's advice:

> The most effective debugging tool
>   is still careful thought, coupled with
>   judiciously placed print statements.
>
> -- *"Unix for Beginners" (1979)*

The immediate fix is to `os.path.join()` the directory name back in front; but you also really need to get rid of the global variable.

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

fromadd = 'fromadd@gmail.com'
toadd = 'toadd@gmail.com'

def send(pathname, froma, toa):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = froma
    msg['To'] = toa
    msg['Subject'] = 'Photos'

    text = MIMEText('Pics')
    msg.attach(text)

    # Should really close() when done!
    screenshot_data = open(pathname, 'rb').read()
    webcam_data = open(pathname, 'rb').read()

    screenshot_image = MIMEImage(screenshot_data, name=os.path.basename(pathname))
    webcam_image = MIMEImage(webcam_data, name=os.path.basename(pathname))

    msg.attach(screenshot_image)
    msg.attach(webcam_image)

    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', '587')
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo()
    session.login(froma, 'Password')
    session.sendmail(froma, toa, msg.as_string())
    session.quit()

def main():
    for basename in os.listdir(r'C:\NONE'):
        filename = os.path.join([r'C:\NONE', basename])
        # switch order of conditions for minor efficiency hack
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") and os.path.isfile(filename):
            send(filename, fromadd, toadd)
            print('File Sent: ' + filename) 
            os.remove(filename)
        # empty else not required

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Notice also how I renamed several of the variables to avoid plurals on singular instances and hopefully better connect related variables by using a common prefix.

It's still not clear why you send two copies of each image, or why you create a text part when you don't have anything useful to put in it. You might also want to avoid the legacy `sendmail` method in accordance with the recommendation in its documentation. And why do you create a separate message for each photo? Attaching all the photos to a single email message will surely be more practical (unless the pics are absolutely huge and the message becomes too big for your mail server; but surely then email is the wrong tool for this anyway).

More fundamentally, you should not be writing new code in Python 2 in 2018; and incidentally, some of this would be somewhat more straightforward with the overhauled `email` library in 3.6+ (though it's still low-level and quirky).

Comment: what do you mean by ```then email is the wrong tool for this anyway```? Is there another way of sending large number of images at once?

Comment: Upload them to a file sharing site and send links.